# Use the axiom of regularity to demonstrate that if $A$ and $B$ are two sets, then either $A\notin B$ or $B\notin A$ (or both): Proof Assistance

Tags: proof-writing, set-theory

In Tao's Analysis I, the following exercise is posed:

> Use the axiom of regularity (and the singleton set axiom) to show that if $A$ is a set, then $A \notin A$. Furthermore, show that if $A$ and $B$ are two sets, then either $A\notin B$ or $B\notin A$ (or both).

I was able to demonstrate the first portion of this (i.e. that $A \notin A$), but I am having trouble formulating the proof necessary to demonstrate the second claim. Here is what I have so far.

Firstly, if $A = B$, then we know by $A\notin A$ that the statement $A\notin B \lor B\notin A$ is true, so let's consider the case where $A \neq B$.

Define $A=\{...\}$ and $B=\{...'\}$. (just my shorthand notation for denoting that they contain different elements and are therefore not equal).

Consider the case where $A \in B$. Then we have $B = \{A,...' \}$. Suppose also, by contradiction, that $B\in A$. Then we could rewrite $B=\{A,...'\}$ as $B=\{\{B,...\},...'\}$. But because $A\in B$, we could then rewrite $B$ as $B=\{\{\{A,...'\},...\},...'\}$. This process would continue infinitely.

I believe there is a contradiction here because I remember reading something about infinitely nested sets not being allowed in set theory where the axiom of regularity is asserted...so I think I am close.

What I see so far (in the little nested examples that I presented), is that $A=\{\{A,...'\},...\}$. I feel like this somehow contradicts the idea that $A \notin A$, but I am not certain why.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.  By regularity,
{A,B} has an element that is disjoint from {A,B}.

Comment: $(A \cap \{A,B\} = \emptyset) \lor (B \cap \{A,B\}=\emptyset)$. This results in the statement: $(A \notin A \land B \notin A) \lor (B \notin B \land A\notin B)$ . Is that what you're getting at?

Comment: Yes, you can take a hint.